# How to read rows after empty row in the Google spreadsheet?

Tags: gdata-api, google-sheets-api, gdata-python-client

I'm using [gdata-python-client](http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/articles/python_client_lib.html) to read data from a Google spreadsheet. My code for reading rows is as follows:

```
import gdata.speadsheet.text_db

gd_client = gdata.spreadsheet.text_db.DatabaseClient(
                     username=setting['account_name'],
                     password=setting['account_pass'])

xls_db = gd_client.GetDatabases(spreadsheet_key=setting['spreadsheet_id'])
first_sheet = xls_db[0].GetTables()[0]
entries = first_sheet.GetRecords(1, 200)
```

Let's say, the spreadsheet has 160 rows and the 12<sup>th</sup> row is empty. When I try to read all 160 rows using the above code, it only reads the first 11 rows (that is, until it gets the empty 12<sup>th</sup> row). If the spreadsheet doesn't have any empty rows, the code reads all 160 rows.

When I try to read the next rows from the empty row, it returns nothing. for example:

```
entries = first_sheet.GetRecords(50, 55) # entries is None
```

How can I read all the rows from a Google spreadsheet which contains empty rows.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry, may be it's too late, I just found this question. :)

So, here is the documentation of Google Docs spreadsheet API:

http://code.google.com/apis/spreadsheets/data/3.0/developers_guide.html

and there is the answer:

> The list feed contains all rows after the first row up to the first
>   blank row.

BTW, I think when the feed ends, there aren't much rows; you see it in vain. :)

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

You can use `CellFeed` in case your spreadsheet has empty rows in between.